Authentication and Security in Django/QT Application
I'm currently working on an application that utilizes Django for the backend and QT/C++/QML for the frontend. One of the key aspects I'm focusing on is authentication and ensuring the security of the application.
Here's a brief overview of how it works: When a user logs in, the frontend sends a request to the API, and if the credentials are valid, the user receives a TOKEN, which is then stored in a class variable. Subsequently, this token is sent with each subsequent request to the API.
Now, my question is: Is this approach secure? Where should such a token be stored? Is using a class variable acceptable in this scenario? It's worth mentioning that this application doesn't handle sensitive data, but I still want to ensure proper security measures are in place.
I'd appreciate any insights or recommendations on best practices for authentication and security in this context.
Thank you!
I was tried to store the data in variable inside the CPP class.

Given you say you're storing it in a variable, you're basically storing it in memory, the storage doesn't really get more secure than that. Regarding "insights or recommendations on best practices for" that lacks focus and isn't a suitable question for Stack Overflow.
